# SQL query from 2 tables. Select and Search

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I have 2 tables. svt_product and svt_user_obj
svt_product have all information, and svt_user_obj have info about creator and updater.

Here is structures http://clip2net.com/s/5Y8rn6 - svt_user_obj
http://clip2net.com/s/5Y8VYJ - svt_product..

Need 2 SQL Queries.

1. SELECT all 
   from svt_product 
   where svt_user_obj.creator = 40 
   and where svt_product.rooms=5 (for example)
2. SELECT all 
   from svt_product 
   and from svt_user_obj 
   where svt_product.id 
   and svt_user_obj.id = 123123.

Comment: See how others have asked questions.

Comment: I guess you've attempted to write those queries yourself?

Comment: please try to solve your problem or search on google  before asking there

Comment: Sure. i was try... Just i don't understand how it work... Then i ask it here. It's bad?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Query 1**

```
SELECT *
FROM svt_product  svt INNER JOIN svt_user_obj obj
ON svt.id = obj.id
WHERE obj.created = 40 and svt.rooms = 5
```

**Query 2**

```
SELECT *
FROM svt_product  svt INNER JOIN svt_user_obj obj
ON svt.id = obj.id
WHERE obj.id = 123
```